# Quality option not working in cordova camera plugin

Tags: windows, cordova

I have a mobile application that allows uploading images either via camera or choosing it from a photo library. While uploading the user is prompted if he or she wants a high quality image to be uploaded or not. If yes, quality option is set to 100 else set to 50. This seems to work fine for android and ios builds but not for windows build. Even after selecting the high quality option, the image uploaded has low quality.Is there something that I'm missing? A plugin that might need to be added specific to windows to make stuff work?
Please help.

I've included a part of the code snippet:
.factory('$Camera', function ($q, $crypt, $settings) {

```
return {
    getPicture: function () {
        var q = $q.defer();

        var options = {
            quality: $settings.getValue('uploadHighQualityImage') ? 100 : 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            targetWidth: 500,
            targetHeight: 500
        };

        navigator.camera.getPicture(function (result) {
            // Put the options

            q.resolve(result);
        }, function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
        }, options);

        return q.promise;
    },
```

Comment: Including some code would certainly help. Try providing a [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan Added. Have a look.